# Crash when attempting to filter results of Bluetooth scan

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am writing a toy app for android that uses bluetooth to read characteristics from a fitness band, as such I am only interested in these bands so I am attempting to filter my scan results using this code:

```
private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
            new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (device.getAddress().contains("88:0F:10") | device.getName().equals("MI")) { //For some reason this crashes the app
                        mLeDeviceListAdapter.addDevice(device);
                        mLeDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

The trouble is that when I run this code the app immediately crashes, specifically on the conditional, without it the app runs perfectly.
What could be causing this crash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite condition in next way:

```
if (device.getAddress() != null && device.getAddress().contains("88:0F:10") && device.getName() != null && device.getName().equals("MI")) {
...
}
```

Method [BluetoothDevice.getName()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#getName()) can return null.

Answer (score 1):

The or conditional should have two pipe characters:

> if (device.getAddress().contains("88:0F:10") || device.getName().equals("MI"))

Comment: It does, that was a error copying from android studio my bad